# JSON Stringify Format Array

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

Let say I have JSON object below:

```
var name = [
{
    "first": "juan",
    "last": "delaCruz"
},
{
    "first": "james",
    "last": "bond"
}
```

]

Can we use `JSON.stringify` to have the output:

```
juan, james
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` can't produce the string `juan, james`, since that isn't legal JSON.

Comment: Note: That 1st snippet isn't JSON. It's a JavaScript literal. Similar syntaxes; different uses (code or data).

Comment: Write a replacer function and mix the two together

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `pluck`, [like in underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck). A basic implementation looks like this:

```
function pluck(collection, key) {
    return collection.map(function(el) {
        return el[key];
    });
}


var name = [{
    first: 'juan',
    last:'dela Cruz'
}, {
    first: 'james',
    last:'bond'
    }
];

var fullname = pluck(name, 'first');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the expected output doesn't appear to be valid JSON, you won't be able to get it with just `JSON.stringify()`.

But, you could combine [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to accomplish it:

```
var firsts = name.map(function (entry) {
    return entry.first;
});

console.log(firsts.join(', ')); // juan, james
```

`.map()` is new with ECMAScript 5, so it'll be readily available in IE 9+ and other modern browsers. And, MDN includes a [good polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) to add it in older browsers.